# None of the FB widgets work on my HTML page (like button & page display)

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, user-interface, web

So I'm making this web page and I'm trying to include the Facebook widget for the like button and the page display but neither will show up on my page.  I have included widgets from other sites (Instagram and Twitter) that work just fine but FB's just won't show up.  The like button is completely not there (although there is very much a space for it when I draw a red border around where it should be) and the page display just shows a text link that links to the page itself.  Here is the code where I include the FB widgets:

```
<body id="background">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="toolbar">
    <input id="input" type="email" placeholder="Join our mailing list!">
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/xuanrongmusic" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/XuanRkRong" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @XuanRkRong</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
</div>
...
</body>
```

I tried making a FB AppID but I may have done it wrong and am kind of confused about that process...

Also not sure if this matters but I'm testing my website offline...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the HTML part ? and you need to have a appId :

```
connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=XXXXXXX";


<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="false">
  <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">
       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find more help in the facebook dev page [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin)

Comment: I'm not missing the <html> part...its just a really big file so I cut that out of the code I included.  And thanks!  Should I just include that "connect.facebook..." line of code in the body?  Or in the head?  Also I'm really confused about the AppID thing...I tried making one but it didn't work?  Or I may have done the process wrong...

Comment: The AppID is the link between your app and your like button. You need to generate one in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually **does** work. It just doesn't appear to work properly if you are testing your files on your local computer or in a sandboxed iframe (ie jsFiddle or codepen). The html file needs to be uploaded to a web server for it to work properly.

Screenshot of your code working on my personal web server:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem--only the link to my FB page would display on my WordPress web page, not the options. This happened in three different browsers, with any WordPress theme, no matter where I inserted the javascript. Then I found the plugin displayed properly in my phone's browser and realized that the problem was the Disconnect app installed on my laptop, which blocks social media connections. Once I whitelisted my website in Disconnect in one browser, it displays fine in all browsers.